# how to use my radeon 6950 graphics card instead of Intel Graphics 4000

Tags: graphics, amd-radeon, intel-graphics

I have just recently put my build together, and I have installed my graphics card. The problem is that when i look at my computer's display it is saying that I am using the intel graphics that came with my CPU. Is there a way that i can get the Radeon graphics to run instead?

Also, I tried plugging a DVI cable into the graphics card itself and my monitor was unable to receieve the signal. Is there a reason to that?

Comment: what motherboard? Many have a setting in the BIOS screens to define which is the primary display

Comment: The motherboard is a Biostar z77 LGA 1155

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to have the output of any add-in graphics card route through the motherboard's VGA/DVI connector because there is no path to do so. The motherboard's VGA/DVI connector is only there to allow you to use the on-board integrated graphics.

Firstly, you should have your monitor hooked up to the Radeon card directly. Secondly, make sure that you have the card properly seated and that any external power connectors are plugged in so that the card is getting power.

If you still aren't seeing anything output from your Radeon card, hook your monitor back up to the integrated graphics and boot into the BIOS menu. Make sure that you select "external graphics adapter" (or whatever is similar) as your primary display device. Then hook the monitor back up to the graphics card and reboot.

You should be seeing output on the monitor from the Radeon card, now.

Note that when you are using a graphics card, you cannot use your integrated graphics alongside it. It's an either-or proposition.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to use a cable from the graphics card to the monitor. When you tried that it didn't work you said, but verify this:

- On the monitor pick the correct (DVI) input signal to use. Remove any other (graphics cable, vga, dvi, displayport, hdmi etc)
- If that doesn't help shutdown and startup again with the cable only connected to the Radeon graphics card
- As @Sean mentioned in a comment, there could be a setting in the motherboard bios for this.

Answer (score 0):

looking at the TZ77XE4 (there is more than 1 version of the Z77) I see that the steps appear to be:

1. Chipset menu
2. System agent (SA) configuration
3. Graphics Configuration
4. Primary Display

Primary Display
*This item select which of IGFX/PEG/PCI Graphics device should be Primary
Display or select SG for Switchable Gfx.*
Options: Auto (Default) / IGFX / PEG / PCI

If you can't find the manual for your motherboard, then you should be able to download it from [here](http://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/mb/index.php?S_ID=13)

Comment: so out of AUTO/ IGFX/ PEG/ PCI which one should i select?

Comment: my guess would be PEG (PCI-Express Graphics)

Answer (score 0):

you should change the primary display to PCI in the bios. If the card still does not display anything, you should try disabling the on-board/integrated graphics which should be found in the same section of your bios.

In the unlikely event that this does not fix the problem, i would be checking device manager to see if the device is actually working properly, if not, it may display errors and you may be able to debug the problem from there. Also you should install the latest drivers for your [graphics card](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/amd-radeon-hd-6000/hd-6850/pages/amd-radeon-hd-6850-overview.aspx#4)(if you haven't already), your much better off with the latest on the manufacturers site than the ones provided on the disc your card came with.